# Mixing "core" form components and "angular" form components

Tags: vmware-clarity

We are in the upgrade process to clarity v5 and I want to know what's your suggested way to migrate forms to core components.
Main reason for this question is when I have to use components of both "worlds" (if something is not implemented in core yet e.g. combobox) and the layout of them.
As the angular components use clr-col classes and core components do it more dynamically.
So how to align them the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding mixing the two. The main reason is that some improvements in the Core form controls may generate different slightly different outcomes, and blending them might cause more work than you gain.

This is unproven, but you might have more success mixing if you try to use the Core Control as the input wrapper, but you could put the Angular Combobox (or other custom form controls) inside of it. That would help lessen the layout differences that you might have to custom manage.